# How to check if hour in text is between midnight?

Tags: php

The result is:

```
Friday, 26 January, 2018 23:40 - 00:50
```

I basically make a xml guide, and the program which in the area of midnight and a little after, saved as in the example:

```
<programme start="20180126234000 +0200" stop="20180126005000 +0200" channel="20">
<title lang="he">******</title>
<desc lang="he">*******</desc>
</programme>
```

The date obtained at 'stop' is the same date as in 'start' (26),

I'm looking for a simple way to calculate the program,

Example:

```
$time = 23:40 - 00:50
// If the time between today (26) and tomorrow (27)
echo "yes";
```

Comment: That's bad data. `stop` should be `20180127005000 +0200` otherwise your event's run-time is technically time-reversed and physics doesn't like that.

Comment: This is the logic that i think it might work.. get the time diff between 23:40 to 00.50.. u will get 1 hr 10 mins. then use programme start date time and + the time diff, you will get a future date. if future date != programme start date then echo yes.

Comment: If `stop` is less than `start`, you could assume that they actually meant thenext date and it spans midnight. Add a day to the `stop` date.